# Update a row in Spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am having a table in Postgress DB.
Employee.

```
 @Entity
 public class Employee implements Serializable {

  public  Employee(){

  }

  public  Employee(long id){
    this.empID = id;
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  long empID;

  @Version
  public Long version;

String name;
String city;
int age;


public long getEmpID() {
    return empID;
}

public void setEmpID(long empID) {
    this.empID = empID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@OneToOne(orphanRemoval=true)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
BankAccount bankAccount;

public BankAccount getBankAccount() {
    return bankAccount;
}

public void setBankAccount(BankAccount bankAccount) {
    this.bankAccount = bankAccount;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
Collection<Project> projects;

public Collection<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}
public void setProjects(Collection<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}
```

}

Here is my Employee Service Update function.

```
 public Employee updateEmployee(Employee employee){
    employee.setName("Updated name");
    employeeRepository.save(employee);

    return employee;
}
```

Request Data: JSON
Request Method:PUT

```
{
  "empID":"1",
  "name":"New",
 "city":"Agra"
 }
```

Above service function is working fine when request is provided with empID , it's updating the same record.

But Problem started when @Version annotation is included in Employee Domain, it's creating new row on every request, Kindly suggest what is going wrong??

Comment: What is the initail value in the column corresponding to the version field?

Comment: @ManishKothari 0 is a first value,, but iinitiallly version is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you can insert multiple rows with same `empID` but anyway.

If you send your PUT request with @Version field in your Domain class. When `@Versio`n is `null` it will be treated as a new entry and will be inserted.

```
{
  "empID":"1",
  "name":"New",
  "city":"Agra"
}
```

Try sending a value for version in your PUT request.

```
{
  "empID":"1",
  "name":"New",
  "city":"Agra",
  "version":"0"
}
```

Comment: your solution gave me an idea , how can i work with version 
but  , for every update do I need to provide version ,, or is there any way that i don't have to provide  version in request???

Comment: If it is an existing record. You need to send the version. This is used for Optimistic Locking and required.

Comment: Above solution , works well can you share some another way of updating data of row with version , 
As per requirement , i don't want to send version in every request for every update .

Comment: Then you will need to do a get by id first and then set the values to update and update